# BOW not considered all elements

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm working with the possibility of applying the BOW method to generate vectors for represented chords. However, when I use this method, I can generate the vectors, but not all chords are considered.

Here is the code elaborated:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
```

```
# DF
    music   chords
0   1.wav   N, A7, Am7, Am7b5/G, A7, N
1   2.wav   N, Em, C, D, Em, C, D, N
2   3.wav   N, E, A, E, B, A, D6, E, N
```

```
#BOW
bow = CountVectorizer(max_features=1000, ngram_range=(1,1))
train_bow = bow.fit_transform(df['chords'])
pd.DataFrame(bow.transform(df['chords']).toarray(), columns=sorted(bow.vocabulary_.keys()))

#Result
    a7  am7 am7b5   d6  em
0   2   1   1      0     0
1   0   0   0      0     2
2   0   0   0      1     0
```

See, for example, that chords like C, D and A are not counted. Does anyone understand what I might be wrong?

Comment: probabily the default tokenizer of CountVectorizer is not the best for your strings.
maybe you should write a custom one and pass it through the tokenizer parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how the default tokenizer of sklearn works, but it's not appropriate for your input.

```
tokenizer = lambda x: x.replace(" ", "").split(",")
bow = CountVectorizer(max_features=1000, tokenizer = tokenizer, ngram_range=(1,1))
train_bow = bow.fit_transform(df['chords'])
pd.DataFrame(bow.transform(df['chords']).toarray(), columns=sorted(bow.vocabulary_.keys()))
```

printing the output:

```
>>> bow.vocabulary_.keys()
dict_keys(['n', 'a7', 'am7', 'am7b5/g', 'em', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'd6'])
```

Comment: A little question: why does the N appear twice?

Comment: some space are not removed, let me check

Comment: now it should work

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one method to manualy create the vocabulary and another to tokenize.

the output is the one that follows:

```
>>>
   b  d  am7  c  em  n  a  e  a7  am7b5/g  d6
0  0  0    1  0   0  2  0  0   2        1   0
1  0  2    0  2   2  2  0  0   0        0   0
2  1  0    0  0   0  2  2  3   0        0   1
```

Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def voc(chord):
    items = []
    for item in chord:
        items += item.split(', ')
        items = [el.lower() for el in items]
    vocabulary = list(set(items))
    return vocabulary

def tokenizer(item):
    items = []
    items = item.split(', ')
    items = [el.lower() for el in items]
    return items

df = pd.read_excel("df.xlsx") #I created a df for test purpose, replace with yours


chord = list(df['chords'].values)

vocabulary = voc(chord)
#BOW
bow = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = vocabulary, tokenizer = tokenizer, max_features=1000, ngram_range=(1,1))
train_bow = bow.fit_transform(df['chords'])
bow = pd.DataFrame(bow.transform(df['chords']).toarray(),columns=bow.vocabulary_.keys())
```

Let me know if that's what you needed!